# Delphi Rio 10.3.1 Xml Data Binding with duplicate segment name

Tags: delphi, data-binding, schema, wizard

I am new to XML processing and Delphi data binding wizard.

I'm trying to process and XSD that contain 2 segment with the same identifier name but different content
and i've found that the parser is missing the second segment at all, confusing the data details of the second segment with the ones of the first. The data type details of the second part are processed into the unit but not related to any component

This is the schema where i have
 and  that both have a subsegment with same name  but different content. When i process detalhead1 i only find in it the segments of detailhead1 related to infohead1 and not the ones related to detailhead1.
Is there an option into the Ide to let it separate the segment correctly?
During the wizard use i can choose single schema component and change the identifier name associated to a data type. The point is that in that part of the wizard i find only one data type (detailhead1 present into infohead1) and not both

This is the schema example with simplified data details
(i am not the owner/handler of the schema that i can change it)

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="datas.xsd"/>
    <xs:complextype name="Head1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Codeone" type="String6"/>
            <xs:element name="Datahead1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="infohead1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="head1field">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:element name="fieldONE" type="string2"/>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Detailhead1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="head1field">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:element name="fieldTWO" type="string33"/>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complextype>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your message to show a minimal reproducible example showing the problem you experience. We cannot help you without seeing the code you use. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Alex, try to feed the parser a real word xml file (that contains the duplicate element), in my experience, this works better than feeding it the xsd.

Comment: @fpiette i could not add another example, The full XSD i very complex.i tried to reproduce this small example. Delphi wizard is missing the second segment that have the same tag name. The generated unit is complex. would be not easier to navigate here online if i show it. you should navigate throgh all the code too see missing parts.
i made a trick
i've changed manually the second tagname into the schema, i have head1field and head1field_suffix now. i can now import all the schema and generate a well formatted XML but  i need to manipulate the generated xml to  restore the original tag names

Comment: @whosrdaddy i  need to import the XSD to have a unit with the binding classes to can create the XML file from the schema. the XSD is a complex type
i don't know, shoud i import into the wizard the XML generated with that schema?

Comment: To be honest, delphi's xml databinding wizard is not very smart. it works for simple schema's but once they get complex it simply fails. If you know that the XSD is stable (ie it will not change for quite a while) I would generate from an actual xml file (that adheres to the schema), most of the times I got better results usiong that method. I must say that I have completely abandoned the binding wizard as I have built my own import tool chain and use RTTI to serialize/deserialize XML to/from plain delphi objects (aka PODO's)...

Comment: If you not succeed in your task using Delphi, you could take a look at other tools too, actually C# is quite good with XML (and java, but I really hate java)

Comment: @whosrdaddy same problem. i've imported the generated XML  and the compiler wizard use the same class name (also if the fields are different) for the different segment
rightnow my trick seems the only solution that forces me to pass the XML to a string and make a stringreplace removing to all the tag names the prefix i added manually
just wondering if this is a Delphi wizard limit of is an uncommon rule to generate a schema

Comment: ^^ Read my last comments, as I said, the binding wizard is not very smart :)

Comment: i have a full application alreading working in delphi i cannot change the language. anyway i found a fix. using the XML is not improving the automation unfortunately